# Angular 6 aws-sdk only cognito identity credentials use

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am using `angular 6` and `aws-sdk` node modules in my project.

I only used cognito service of `aws-sdk`, not all functionality.

I am running the `ng build --build-optimizer --aot` command.

It takes too much data on build time.

My `main.ts` file size is around 3.3 MB and `aws-sdk` takes around 1.3 MB.

I am using this command:

```
import * as AWS from 'aws-sdk'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need to use

```
import AWS = require('aws-sdk');
```

it imports the entire sdk

```
import AWS = require('aws-sdk/global');
```

it imports only AWS object without service

```
import S3 = require('aws-sdk/clients/s3');
```

it imports only s3 service.